# Action when click on input with atttributes

Tags: jquery

I have that :

```
<p><input data-cancel="82" rel="0" name="returnfb82" role="button" value="en cours" type="button"></p>
```

I want action when we click on input where data-cancel = 82

I make taht but boesn't work

```
$( "[data-cancel]" ).on( "click", function () {
alert("test");
});
```

Thanks you for your Help !:)

Comment: why are you making yourself doing the hard work? why not create a class then call it right? adding a class on the input does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

`$("[data-cancel]")` selector will select all the elements having `data-cancel` attribute, for your case try something like this :-

```
$('[data-cancel="82"]').on('click', function() {
   alert("test");
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/n0cfdxup/9/)

**EDIT :-**(As per OP's comment)

If you want value to be dynamic instead of static `82` then try this :-

```
var myval = 82;//store value in a variable

$('[data-cancel="'+ myval +'"]').on('click', function() {
   alert("test");
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/n0cfdxup/11/)

Comment: Hello Thanks for your reply, However, "82" is a variable, can be something other than 82 ( this is according to my request sql)

Comment: @Fabien14... you can store the value coming from sql to variable say `myval` and then use this `$('[data-cancel="'+myval'"]').on('...`

Answer (score -1):

Use this code :

```
jQuery("input[data-cancel='82']").on( "click", function () {
alert("test");
});
```

Actually you need to specify attribute `data-cancel='82'`